# Run maximum 2 process at any instant of time

Tags: python, shell, unix, pyspark

I have spark application, which I can execute for number of different client.
But I want to make sure at any instant only 2 client is running, and if one finishes execution start next excution.
How to achieve this?

```
example:
spark-submit Prg1.py -t0000 -c123
spark-submit Prg1.py -t0000 -c456
spark-submit Prg1.py -t0000 -c789
spark-submit Prg1.py -t0000 -c012
```

When I will execute above 4 commands in different session, I want to make sure only 2 process are running and remaining will start only when they one of the process completes.

Comment: In which platform you would like to run these process? UNIX?

Comment: Yes in Unix only.

Comment: Is it fine if I help you with this in shell script? Also if you use ps -ef command did you see the process with Prag1.py? or its a different process name? I need the process name to help you?

Comment: I can see process name with the name Prg1.py only. Shell script is fine.

Comment: Hi, Poonam try with my answer below. All tag this question 'shell-script` so that other people can take benefit from it.

Comment: I am not familiar with `spark-submit` but is it synchronous (i.e. it returns when the job is complete) or asynchronous (i.e. it returns immediately)?

Comment: @Poonam, you can replace this line total_running_proces=``ps -fu $USER|grep -v "grep"|grep "Prg1.py"| awk '{print $2}'|wc -l``  with total_running_proces=`ps -fu $USER|grep -v "grep" |grep -c tail`

Answer (score 0):

Please see below shell program for your requirement. $USER, if this environment variable is not set put the user id who is going to run the below shell script.

1. Create a file like `clients.txt` and add all the client number in it like below
   123
   456
   789
   012

Now create a shell script file `spark_submit.sh` and add the below lines in it:-

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
filename="$1"
total_running_proces=`ps -fu $USER|grep -v "grep"|grep "Prg1.py"| awk '{print $2}'|wc -l`
if [ $total_running_proces -ge 1 ]; then
   echo "Process is already running"
   exit 0
fi
while [ 1 ]
do
   total_running_proces=`ps -fu $USER|grep -v "grep"|grep "Prg1.py"| awk '{print $2}'|wc -l`
   if [ $total_running_proces -le 1 ]; then
        read -r line
        client=$line
        if [ ${client:-1} -eq 1 ]; then
           break
        else
          spark-submit Prg1.py -t0000 -c$client > /dev/null 2>&1 &
        fi
  fi
  sleep 10 #sleep for 10 second and release the cpu
done < "$filename"
exit 0
```

Now make this file executable `chmod 777  spark_submit.sh`
Now run the program like `./spark_submit.sh clients.txt`

The same script you can use for different process as well. You just need to change line number 5 `grep "pgg1.py"` and line number 12 `spark-submit Prg1.py -t0000 -c$client`
If you need any more help please let me know.

Comment: May want to add a `sleep` call in the `while` loop to keep from spinning one cpu @ 100% utilization; length of the `sleep` call will depend on how quickly the `spark-submit Prg1.py` program takes to run and how quickly all invocations need to complete; for example, if the program takes 5 minutes to run and the total run has a (relatively) low priority, then `sleep 30` would likely suffice (and greatly reduce cpu usage of this script); may also want to consider what happens if multiple copies of this script are run concurrently (eg, make sure only 1 copy runs at a time?)

Comment: Yes agree and good question as well. I think we are here to just give some solution not to provide full program. Developer also need to take some initiative from their end as well. Anyway I have modified the script as per your advice.

Comment: @Abhijit I am running process concurrently, so I can't use clients.txt as parameter.

Comment: With clients.txt as parameter also jobs will run concurrently. At a time any two instance will run. First try and see. I think you raised your concern without testing. Run the script first and execute the below command from different terminal  `ps -ef | grep Prg1.py`. You should see two parallel process all the time. But sometimes you might see one process for 10 second because of the `sleep` statement. But you must run in background with `> /dev/null 2>&1 &`

Comment: `grep | grep | awk | wc` is rather clumsy! Maybe use `grep -c "[P]rg1.py"`

Comment: @MarkSetchell good option, but still you need `grep -v "grep"`

Comment: No, `grep "[g]rep"` doesn't find `grep` 